# CURL --interface not working: "Couldn't bind to ..." error

Tags: curl

I'm trying to use curl with another IP address from the ones available in the server but I get this error:

```
curl --interface 41.141.41.23 http://www.google.com
```

curl: (45) Couldn't bind to 41.141.41.23 (its just an example address)

It only lets me do it with the main one and only by the interface name:

```
curl --interface eth0 http://www.google.com
```

I'm using:

Ubuntu 12.04

curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there is a bug in Curl when using --interface if the domain requested is using both ipv4 and ipv6 instead of just ipv4 you have to add --ipv4 to work.

So thats the case with www.google.com, so to make it work would be:

```
curl --interface 41.141.41.23 --ipv4 http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Could You be more specific, please?

1. What curl version are You using?
2. What OS are You running?
3. Does `curl --verbose --interface 41.141.41.23 http://www.google.com` show anything more specific?

It seams that You have restricted access to /proc directory...

Comment: Thank you for the help. I added the versions to the bottom of the answer. About with verbose, doesn't give more information than that: *   Trying 2a00:1450:4007:804::1010... getaddrinfo(3) failed for 41.141.41.23:0
* Couldn't bind to '41.141.41.23'
* Closing connection #0
curl: (45) Couldn't bind to '41.141.41.23'

Comment: hmmm... Could You please show output of `ls -ald /proc/net` and `ls -ald /proc/self/net`? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955724/regular-user-cant-read-proc-net-dev

Sounds like a similar problem. Is it GrSecurity enabled kernel too?

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is `curl --interface iface-name ....`, for example `curl --interface tun0 google.com`.

Comment: That's not correct. Quoting from the manpage `--interface <name> Perform  an  operation using a specified interface. You can enter interface name, IP address or host name.`

Comment: Does curl Windows supprt specific "--interface"?